# Laravel Socialite - Sending Email After Login

Tags: laravel

I know that you can use the user's google account to login using Laravel Socialite.

Can i use the email account of that logged-in user to send email?

I am currently doing this using the config/mail.php settings which is pointed to the .env file. As far as I know the mail server will only allow the application to send email after it was authenticated and is only possible by sending your email and password on the mail server.

Can I also do sending of email using the logged-in credentials of the user logged using his google account without using the settings on config/mail.php?

**The requirement is that the sender email must be the email of the current login user.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The requirement is that the sender email must be the email of the current login user.

Most mail servers will reject these spoofed emails.
Since your application is not the owner of the email address, you cannot send using that email address.

Comment: thank you for confirming what i have said on my question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm in a project, where the client asked me, so that when the system sends an email, it goes out through the email of the user logged in with google, I believe that's what you're looking for...

I am using this google authorization scope

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.send_mail